# TFS MSBuild not restoring nugets for websites in solution

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild

I have a rather big solution with around 90 projects, in Visual Studio 2015 it builds just fine, but when I tried to do a CI in TFS, it looks like the nuget restore ignores the packages.config for all the **websites** in my solution, thus not loading its packages and failing to build.

i.e.

- If its a .csproj the nugets for that project are restored just fine
- If its a website it seems to ignore its packages.config

**p.s.**
I would prefer a solution where i didn't have to check in anything extra regarding those projects, such as '*add the dll to the bin folder it to check-in the .refresh file [...]s*', so the CI process is as automatic as possible

**Update1:**

- specifying path to nuget.exe (ver: 4.9.2) i get a new error saying '**WARNING: Project file [path to proejct] cannot be found**'

**Update2** (Build Definition - NuGet Installer component):

- Path to Solution: 'correct path to solution..'
- Path NuGet.config: 'correct path to NuGet.config'
- Disable local cache, checked
- NuGet Arguments: empty
- Path to NuGet.exe: $(NuGetPath), path set in Variables

Comment: Can you share your build definition?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, but i dont know; how would i do that? :D

Comment: Print screen...?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk looks like an overkill, i thought there was a link, ill list the configs with their values in an update

Comment: Try cloaking any packages and bin folders and see if that makes a difference. I've run into issues with the build tasks where if there is any remnant of the packages the restore is skipped. Are you using the Nuget Restore task (like you should be) or using the Visual Studio build task with the restore packages checkbox checked? Also assuming you're using the vs build task (in general) do you have it set to use 2017 or 2015?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 [greatest band ever], nuget restore seems to work in general, the .csproj files restore their packages fine, the issue is with the website projects that dont have the .csproj file

Comment: Oh I've misunderstood. You may have to upgrade the website project to a web application instead. There's definitely a few walk throughs on this site as I stumbled on one the other day.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes am trying to avoid converting them to web apps due to lack of time, but it would be the best solution in the end..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone else having this issue

I followed pinkfloydx33's suggestion and converted all website project to webapps.
it was easier than i thought and straight forward, there still some refactoring to be done on those projects but everything works perfectly